# Foundation scripts doesnt work with Django app

Tags: jquery, python, django, zurb-foundation

Have a problem trying to get an Orbit Foundation slider work in my Django template.

Ill start from the beginning:

My Django project url.py file has one url only:

```
url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
```

And an app's url.py file has:

```
url(r'^', 'myapp.views.content'),
```

Then the views.py file:

```
def content(request):

    person_name = Persons.objects.all()[:10].values('name')
    person_id = Persons.objects.all()[:10].values('id')

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'persons_names': person_name, 'persons_ids': person_id})
```

My index.html consists of some basic information and extends base.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} some divs {% endblock %}
```

Base.html file I think is quite standart:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title> {% block title %} MyTitle {% endblock %} </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "static/css/foundation.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "static/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "static/js/foundation/foundation.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "static/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "static/js/vendor/jquery.js" %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">

    {% block header %}
        {% include 'header.html' %}
    {% endblock %}  

</div>

{% block content %} {% endblock %}

<footer>
    {% block footer %}  
        {% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually the problem starts at header.html template where I want to insert my orbit slider:

```
{% block header %}
<ul class="example-orbit-content" data-orbit>
    <li data-orbit-slide="headline-1">
        <div>
            <h2>Headline 1</h2>
            <h3>Subheadline</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-orbit-slide="headline-2">
        <div>
            <h2>Headline 2</h2>
            <h3>Subheadline</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The orbit doesnt work for me. All these h1 and h2 tags are displayed one after another without being formatted as they have to be. I mean, Ive just copy-pasted a test orbit code from foundation documentation page... I thought it should just work -)

Btw, settings.py has all required data (i guess):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
('static', '/home/me/Documents/Django_apps/my_project/static/'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
.....
'django.contrib.staticfiles'
.....
)
```

It seems like django doesnt see my js files... What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

UPDATE:
Console "GET" messages about my CSS and JS files are like:

```
"GET /static/static/js/vendor/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Comment: what is your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting? please paste your HTTP 404 errors from console

Comment: @ambi I don't have STATICFILES_FINDERS settings in my settings.py. If I got it right, the STATICFILES_FINDERS is just collecting all static files from my STATICFILES_DIRS, isnt it? 
Sorry I didnt understand about 404. The only problem I have is visualization of orbit-slider. Or were you talking about something else?

Comment: @ambi I think I relized what you were talking about! In console I see that all .js files are recived by browser. For example: "GET /static/static/js/vendor/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
So the problem is not that Django doesnt see JS's but in something else...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your **base.html** file. You shouldn't be prefixing all of your static assets with `static/`. It should look more like this:

**base.html**

```
<head>
    <title> {% block title %} MyTitle {% endblock %} </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/foundation.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/foundation/foundation.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Unfortunately deleting "static" doesnt help. My links to CSS files works just fine with static/ prefix. Without it they doesnt...